# Why get warning in repository "Unnecessary `@Repository`"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on Spring Boot project. I have repository file in my project but it will show me a warning message in repository class `Unnecessary @Repository`. I am extending a `JpaRepository<>` with my repository. My Spring version is **4** and JDK version is **17**.

Here is my dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is my repository

```java
@Repository // Here I get a warning to remove this annotation becasue its unnecessary
public interface CollegeRepo extends JpaRepository<College, Integer>{
    
}
```

Comment: Might be because extending `JpaRepository` already makes it a repo so Spring would handle it accordingly even without the annotation.

Comment: @Thomas Does it's a good way to wokring with spring like that? because previously when I was working on spring boot this warning was not came in a repository.

Comment: according to the javadoc at org.springframework.data.repository.Repository spring will discover interfaces that extend this interface during classpath scanning.

Comment: I'd assume it's Spring's annotation processor that's generating that warning, right? Can you share a stack trace? Additionally, I can't tell when or why that warning was added but I'd assume there's a good reason for this which probably is not grave enough to warrant an error.

Comment: That stack trace doesn't seem to be related to your question at all. When I asked for one I was asking for the trace that shows the warning. If there is none because it's in your IDE only then what IDE are you using, how did you configure annotation processing etc.?

Comment: @Thomas I am using a `Sprintg Tool Suites 4` IDE and I know this stack trace is not related to my question

Comment: If the stack trace isn't related to your question why did you post it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are extending `JpaRepository<T, ID>` interface, it means that spring boot must autoconfigure this repository bean for you, namely, it will be configured a proxy bean of [`SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html).

In simple words, we do not just create a bean using `@Repository` or `@Component` annotation, we extend the `spring-data` interface and then our repository bean will be autoconfigured.

Comment: Is it a good way to go further without `@Repository` annotation

Answer (score 5):

### When to use `@Repository`

You want to provide your own implementation of how to access the data layer and what should be done. In this case marking your implementation class with `@Repository` will allow you to have this class managed by spring so that you can autowire necessary fields to access data layer like `EntityManager` , `JdbcTemplate` ...etc. Although `Component`, and `@Repository` in the most fundamental level just register spring beans there are some slight enhancements using `@Repository` which might make it neccessary to use and also best practice in the current case.

As per [doc1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html)

> A class thus annotated with `@Repository` is eligible for Spring
> DataAccessException translation when used in conjunction with a
> PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.,

and [doc2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html)

> PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
>
> Bean post-processor that
> automatically applies persistence exception translation to any bean
> marked with Spring's @Repository annotation, adding a corresponding
> PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor to the exposed proxy

Example of above case use with `@Repository`.

```
@Repository
public class CustomCarRepositoryImpl implements CustomCarRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<CarEntity> findCarsWithSpeed(Integer speed) {

        return entityManager.createQuery("Query to execute")
                .setMaxResults(50).getResultList();
    }
 }

public interface CustomCarRepository { 
     List<CarEntity> findCarsWithSpeed(Integer speed);
}
```

Then you can autowire in your other components the `CustomCarRepository` and access the data layer as you have implemented.

### When Not to use `@Repository`

When you just declare your interface and you extend from any Spring child interface of `Repository` from `org.springframework.data.repository`.

Example

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, Long> {
    List<CarEntity> findCarsWithSpeed(Integer speed);
}
```

In that case `Spring Boot` will be able to create the repository bean for you automatically from `auto configuration`.

The only further action needed is if your own interfaces extending from `Repository` do not exist in the same package or subpackage of where your `@Configuration` or `@SpringBootApplication` exists then you would need

- either `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"base-package-where-repositories-exist"})`
- or `@AutoConfigurationPackage(basePackages = {"base-package-where-repositories-exist"})`

as to help spring boot identify the package it should look for the auto configuration of that repository. ( The later `@AutoConfigurationPackage` will affect both repositories and other things required for auto configuration like entities scan and more. So it should be used with care in a project and not just for repositories.)

Comment: Just to be clear: `@Repository` should only be put on custom implementation classes, right? So to answer the OP's basic question: use the annotation for implementations, don't need it if you only extend interfaces. - Is that summarized correctly?

Comment: @Thomas *you don't need it if you only extend anything down the org.springframework.data.repository.Repository* could sum up when the annotation is not needed.

Comment: Makes sense - maybe add that as a TLDR ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Solution depends upon what type of database you intend to use. "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured." Error you're getting is because you have not set the url for the database in the application.properties. To solve this issue I would recommend you to Open the application.properties and add the following according to your system:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restapi
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP seems to have confused you. You've answered to the problem depicted by the stack trace but according to the OP that's not related to the actual question which is about the `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: @Thomas, I really apologize I should have read his problem statement. Thank you for letting me know 

Comment: No need to apologize, this happens every so often to me as well :)

Comment: @DheerajKashyap I am sorry

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej  Its Alright, Mate!